# UILabels within a UITableView cell are overlaying each other in iOS7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I didn't have this problem with iOS6, but am currently having it with iOS7. I have a UITableView and you can see 8 cells at the time the view is loaded. Each populated with different names from and array. If you scroll down, the next two cells look good, but everything past that gets text laid on top of it; That text being the contents of what was in the previous cells. So the 10th cell will have what was in the first cell, as well as what is supposed to be in the 10th cell laid on top of it.

Code:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (cell == nil) 
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        }

        //Create Label for Name inside cell
        UILabel *name = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 7.0, 5.0, 300.0, 30.0 )];
        [name setText:[self.entriesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


        //Check to see if current person is a Parent or Child
        NSString *class = [self.database getCellDataWithMembership:[self.MembershipArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] andColIndex:4];

        if([class isEqualToString:@"CHILD"])
        {
            name.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:25.0f/255.0f green:111.0f/255.0f blue:45.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
            name.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:17.0];                
        }

        [cell.contentView addSubview:name];
        return cell;
}
```

My skill with Table views is makeshift at best. I've been reading lots of documentation and researching solutions, but was not able to come up with a solution. I just find it odd that it works perfect for iOS6, but not for iOS7.

So it fetches a person's name from an array and I want to populate the cells with those names. I was able to originally accomplish this using:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [self.entriesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if([class isEqualToString:@"CHILD"])
{
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:25.0f/255.0f green:111.0f/255.0f blue:45.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:17.0];
```

If I use that instead of the "name" UILabel actions from the first code block, then it displays the names perfectly with no text overlay, but what becomes an issue is the text color. If they are labeled as a CHILD then they should be green text and bold. However, after scrolling down, every person becomes green when they shouldn't be.

Sorry for the lengthy question. I've been working on this and racking my brain around it and I just can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm dynamically adding UI objects to cells. As "caglar" notes, adding and then removing is probs not the best-practice. But, I am doing this also. The way I get around adding loads of UI objects to the cell, each time it's displayed, is by removing all my subviews first. The willDisplayCell delegate then adds them back. Clearly, if you want to remove only certain views, you'll have to tag the view and be more selective with your removal. But you can remove all with the following.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [[cell.contentView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
}
```

Just ensure you're adding / removing your labels to the cell's contentView. In iOS7, you'll remove that too, if you're not careful.

Hope it helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, labels are added to cell whenever `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method is called. I mean you add labels many times. You can remove the label which was added before.

```
//If label was added with tag = 500, remove it
for (UIView *sv in cell.contentView.subviews)
{
    if (sv.tag == 500)
    {
        [sv removeFromSuperview];
    }
}

//Create Label for Name inside cell
UILabel *name = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 7.0, 5.0, 300.0, 30.0 )];
[name setText:[self.entriesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
name.tag = 500;
```

However, this solution is not a good solution. I think creating a custom `UITableViewCell` is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method, when the `cell` is `nil`, you need to creare the `UILabel* name`, then you set the `name` label with a tag `name.tag = 1000`, then you can access this label with this method `UILabel* name = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1000];`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        //Create Label for Name inside cell
        UILabel *name = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 7.0, 5.0, 300.0, 30.0 )];
        name.tag = 1000;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:name];
    }

    UILabel* name = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1000];
    [name setText:[self.entriesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


    //Check to see if current person is a Parent or Child
    NSString *class = [self.database getCellDataWithMembership:[self.MembershipArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] andColIndex:4];

    if([class isEqualToString:@"CHILD"])
    {
        name.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:25.0f/255.0f green:111.0f/255.0f blue:45.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
        name.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:17.0];                
    }

    return cell;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You can set uilabels by using ios6/7 delta shown is size inspector .firstly set your total view for ios7 by changing values x,y,width,height and then change value in ios6/7 delta to make it for ios6 .Hope you get

Comment: Sorry, but this has nothing to do with my issue. I am aware of what you are talking about, but this is irrelevant. I have cells in a UITableView that are repeating over one another basically. Delta values will sadly not fix this :(

Answer (score -2):

you may change the this code.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]; -> UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
```

Comment: I did try that, but the problem is that the user needs the ability to tap on the cell and the program needs to know which cell row was selected so that it can go fetch that index from the array. It no longer overlays when nil, but you can no longer tap on the cell to take you to the next view

Comment: The segue to the other view is being accomplished via a modal segue if that adds any extra details